# How to remove spaces from pagination on CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, spaces

I use the pagination helper from CodeIgniter and it works. But when I see the result in my browser, I can observ unwanted spaces. CodeIgniter seems to insert them in an automatic way.

In my view:

```
<div><?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?></div>
```

The code generated behind (html):

```
<div>
    &nbsp;
    <a href="http://...example.../6">Previous</a>
    &nbsp;
    <a href="http://...example.../">1</a>
    &nbsp;
    <a href="http://...example.../6">2</a>
    &nbsp;
    <strong>3</strong>
    &nbsp;
    <a href="http://...example.../18">4</a>
    &nbsp;
    <a href="http://...example.../24">5</a>
    &nbsp;
    <a href="http://...example.../18">Next</a>
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    <a href="http://...example.../30">Last</a>
</div>
```

So there is a space before my previous link and two spaces before my "Last" link. Same thing happens when it's reversed (two spaces after my "First" link).

Why? It really blow my mind! Please do you know how to remove them?

Any suggestions gratefully received.

**Solution (thanks to uzsolt's answer)** : It works with first_tag_close and last_tag_open set to '' (see comments for more details).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you can set `num_tag_open` and `num_tag_close` config variable.

Comment: It works. Try set `num_tag_open`, `num_tag_close`, `last_tag_open`, `first_tag_close`, `cur_tag_open`, `next_tag_open`, `next_tag_close` config values to `""`.
I tried it now and works.

Comment: Yes you're right. Actually, I decided to keep only `first_tag_close` and `last_tag_open` so I get one space between each element. Thank you, your solution works to remove the two spaces before _Last_ and after _First_. That's exactly what I was expected to.

Comment: This works! I don't see why CI would have spaces sprinkled in by default. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

After trying all sorts of things by setting the config values from both within my controller and a `application/config/pagination.php` file. I managed to solve it by going into `system/libraries/Pagination.php` and reset the default values without any `'&nbsp;'`.

Hope this helps someone else.